# ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing or invalid signature.

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode6-beta7

ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle 'com.google.GPPSignIn3PResources' at bundle path 'Payload/My_app_name.app/GooglePlus.bundle' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate."

I was able to submit same build previously now just did UI related few changes and trying to resubmit the build and getting this error. Is there any solution to handle this ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [AppStore Submission - Missing or invalid signature - com.google.GPPSignIn3PResources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755142/appstore-submission-missing-or-invalid-signature-com-google-gppsignin3presou)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upgrade to the 1.7.1 version of the Google Plus iOS SDK**

Difference between 1.7.0 and 1.7.1 bundles is that no files were added but following three files are deleted.

**Or**

Delete following 3 files from 1.7.0

- `GooglePlus.bundle/GPPSignIn3PResources`
- `GooglePlus.bundle/GPPCommonSharedResources.bundle/GPPCommonSharedResources`
- `GooglePlus.bundle/GPPShareboxSharedResources.bundle/GPPShareboxSharedResources`

Answer (score 11):

The same problem as described here: [AppStore Submission - Missing or invalid signature - com.google.GPPSignIn3PResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755142/appstore-submission-missing-or-invalid-signature-com-google-gppsignin3presou/25767264#25767264)

Just remove files below and build your app as usual!

- `GooglePlus.bundle/GPPSignIn3PResources`
- `GooglePlus.bundle/GPPCommonSharedResources.bundle/GPPCommonSharedResources`
- `GooglePlus.bundle/GPPShareboxSharedResources.bundle/GPPShareboxSharedResources`

Comment: thanks for this. it fixed the issue i was having. +1

Answer (score 0):

A more than one binary may be uploaded to iTunesConnect if the the Build number (Select the Target, then Xcode -> General -> Build, see the picture below) is increased by adding `.1`, i.e. if the version is `3.75`, then increase it to: `3.75.1`, but the Version is still `3.75 for the App (also in iTunesConnect). The build number just has to be unique for each binary that is loaded up to iTunesConnect.

[image: Showing where to set the Build Version in XCode]

After a new binary is uploaded and processed (~ 10 min), then you can select the new binary and submit it for review. In the picture below you may see the old and the new binary listed in iTunesConnect in the Build section of the current App version (you click the plus sign). Then the new binary is selected -> `Saved` -> `Submit for Review`. (Sometimes an error comes when submitting, then just try after a few mins or upload a new binary build).

[image: Showing list of binaries in iTunesConnect]

For those inclined to do this automatically with an Xcode script, here is a description of making an automatic script for updating Build numbers [Better way of incrementing build number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/better-way-of-incrementing-build-number)

Comment: Sorry Hannes I tried your answer but again getting same error.

Comment: @SRSInfosystems You should go to the developer site and download the App distribution profile. Drag it over Xcode (which then installs it) and Quit Xcode. Start it again, select Product -> Clean and then archive and submit.

Answer (score 0):

According to g+ docs, GooglePlus.bundle shouldn't be added to the project

I'm using xcode 6 GM and updated g + to it's latest version (removing GooglePlus.bundle) from the project and got rid of that error

ref: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

(You might run also in an arm64 error if you don't add arm64 to the Valid Architectures in Build Settings)